# Erro ao criar projeto xamarin Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xamarin

Erro ao criar um novo projeto no visual studio, usando xamarin 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

A mensagem de erro diz tudo: você está tentando instalar o pacote num projeto com .NET 4.0, mas o pacote não é compatível com o mesmo, se for possível troque a versão do .NET Framework pra 4.5.

> You are trying to install this package into a project that targets **' .NETFramework,Version=v4.0'**

Veja o texto retirado [da página de requisitos do Xamarin.Forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/installation/)

> The PCL solution template requires Profile 78 which targets .NET 4.5 – this version of .NET can be installed for Visual Studio 2012 (and is included in Visual Studio 2013)